# How could i activate wordpress theme when iphone or ipad detected

Tags: wordpress

I wanna activate/switch wordpress theme when iPhone or iPad is detected.. 
i have already mobile theme which is working on `Tablet (galaxy nexus)`,`Apple iPod` but getting fail in `iPhone` and `iPad` so i need to switch theme.

i am using this code. But does'nt know what to write after detect iPhone/iPad

```
add_filter('browser_detect_function','browser_detect');
    function browser_detect(){
        //setting the variables
            $ipod = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");
            $iphone = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");

            //detecting device
            if ($ipod == true || $iphone == true){
                //does'nt know what to write here. means which funciton         
            }   
    }
```

Comment: Alternatively, I can recommend using the [WPTouch](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wptouch/) plugin.

Comment: thanx for your kind ans sir.but i wants to do it with php code. welcome.

Comment: have u tried @media CSS fuction

Comment: @Arunu: Bhai i have already mobile theme which is working on Tablet (galaxy nexus),Apple iPod but getting fail in iPhone and iPad so i need to switch theme. Can you can give me another solution with css??

Comment: Check if this link is helpful http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/quick-wordpress-theme-switcher-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

Try [WPTouch](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wptouch/) plugin.It will automatically detect the users device.Otherwise check if this [link](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/quick-wordpress-theme-switcher-plugin/) is helpful.

Comment: thanx bhai but this is not good for my solution.. i solved with link which you provide me  in comment " Check if this link is helpful 1stwebdesigner.com/css/quick-wordpress-theme-switcher-plugin "